# trying to append input value with % symbol

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this javascript code that counts a value that is entered at the html side and outputs it in a counter form for a circular graph....

```js
     /* ---------- Circle Progess Bars ---------- */

    function circle_progess() {

      var divElement = $('div'); //log all div elements

      if (retina()) {

        $(".whiteCircle").knob({
          'min': 0,
          'max': 100,
          'readOnly': true,
          'width': 240,
          'height': 240,
          'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
          'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
          'dynamicDraw': true,
          'thickness': 0.2,
          'tickColorizeValues': true
        });

        $(".circleStat").css('zoom', 0.5);
        $(".whiteCircle").css('zoom', 0.999);


      } else {

        $(".whiteCircle").knob({
          'min': 0,
          'max': 100,
          'readOnly': true,
          'width': 120,
          'height': 120,
          'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
          'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
          'dynamicDraw': true,
          'thickness': 0.2,
          'tickColorizeValues': true
        });

      }



      $(".circleStatsItemBox").each(function() {

        var value = $(this).find(".value > .number").html();
        var unit = $(this).find(".value > .unit").html();
        var percent = $(this).find("input").val() / 100;

        countSpeed = 2300 * percent;

        endValue = value * percent;

        $(this).find(".count > .unit").html(unit);
        $(this).find(".count > .number").countTo({

          from: 0,
          to: endValue,

          speed: countSpeed,
          refreshInterval: 50

        });

        //$(this).find(".count").html(value*percent + unit);

      });

    }
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid hideInIE8 circleStats">

  <div class="span3" ontablet="span4" ondesktop="span3">
    <div class="circleStatsItemBox yellow">
      <div class="header">Disk Space Usage</div>
      <span class="percent">percent</span>
      <div class="circleStat">
        <input value="" class="whiteCircle" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <span class="count">
        <span class="number">20000</span>
        <span class="unit">MB</span>
        </span>
        <span class="sep"> / </span>
        <span class="value">
        <span class="number">50000</span>
        <span class="unit">MB</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am basically trying to get to a point where the value that is displayed has a % after it.  Apologies if this doesn't make sense.  The html is here ...

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

After thoroughly going through the source, I noticed that the jQuery Knob plugin is used. The majority of the source is too involved with the plugin so any fix on this source would never yield a working example. So OP must go to the original and complete source and add the following:

> `var endValue = (value * percent) + "%";`
>
> `$('.whiteCircle').val(endValue);`

---

### OLD

---

Try:

> `countSpeed = 2300*percent + "%";`
>
> `endValue = value*percent + "%";`

Not totally following the flow of code, but the gist of it is wherever your var ends up finally, add this to the end `+ "%";`

<del>Maybe your displaying strings? If so try:</del>

<del>> `var X = toString(value*percent) + "%";`</del>

See Snippet it seems to work fine. What element is displaying the result?

#### SNIPPET

```js
var value = .30;
var percent = 100;
var X = value * percent + "%";

document.getElementById('out1').value = X;

//or with jQuery

$('#out2').val(X);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<output id='out1'></output><br/>
<output id='out2'></output>
```

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* ---------- Circle Progess Bars ---------- */

function circle_progess() {

  var divElement = $('div'); //log all div elements

  if (retina()) {

    /*$(".whiteCircle").knob({
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100,
      'readOnly': true,
      'width': 240,
      'height': 240,
      'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
      'dynamicDraw': true,
      'thickness': 0.2,
      'tickColorizeValues': true
    });*/
    $(".circleStat").css('zoom', 0.5);
    $(".whiteCircle").css('zoom', 0.999);


  } else {

    /*$(".whiteCircle").knob({
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100,
      'readOnly': true,
      'width': 120,
      'height': 120,
      'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
      'dynamicDraw': true,
      'thickness': 0.2,
      'tickColorizeValues': true
    });*/

  }



  $(".circleStatsItemBox").each(function() {

    var value = $(this).find(".value > .number").html();
    var unit = $(this).find(".value > .unit").html();
    var percent = $(this).find("input").val() / 100;

    countSpeed = 2300 * percent;

    endValue = value * percent + "%";

    $(this).find(".count > .unit").html(unit);

    var value = .50;
    var percent = 100;

    $('.whiteCircle').val(endValue);

    /* $(this).find(".count > .number").countTo({

       from: 0,
       
       to: endValue,
       speed: countSpeed,
       refreshInterval: 50

     });*/

    //$(this).find(".count").html(value*percent + unit);

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid hideInIE8 circleStats">

  <div class="span3">
    <div class="circleStatsItemBox yellow">
      <div class="header">Disk Space Usage</div>
      <span class="percent">percent</span>
      <div class="circleStat">
        <input value="0" class="whiteCircle" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <span class="count">
        <span class="number">20000</span>
        <span class="unit">MB</span>
        </span>
        <span class="sep"> / </span>
        <span class="value">
        <span class="number">50000</span>
        <span class="unit">MB</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that makes sense to me , tried it but it seems to of just ignored it and dispalys nothing additional

Comment: @greggycoding See update, what element is displaying results?

Comment: circlestat.... it's circle stat that is the element displaying the result right ?

Comment: just tried to add it to the ... var percent = $(this).find("input").val()/100 + "%"; but that didn't wor either

Comment: any ideas on this ? doesnt seem to work wherever i put it tbh lol

Comment: think i read your snippet correclty , but still no presence of a % sign :(

Comment: Did you add it to your real source? The source posted will not work regardless, there's dependencies left out.

Comment: Yeah i added it in

Comment: just doesnt load now

Comment: maybe i should just ignore javascript and hard code a html % sign and place it next to the figure ?

Comment: Very top one starts with var endValue